# Como remover imagens selecionadas dinamicamente antes do submit

Tags: javascript, html

Gostaria de saber como posso remover imagens selecionadas do **input file** antes de envia-las, sou novo em JavaScript, vi diversos exemplos, porém sem a implementação com o botão "submit" e não sei como pegar esses valores, seria algo como isto:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Algo baseado num [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32062876/removing-file-from-multiple-files-uploader-on-button-click-when-using-html5-file) que vi aqui na comunidade

Comment: Podes mostrar o código que estás a usar e referir eventuais bibliotecas que uses (jQuery, Boostrap, MooTools, etc...)

Answer (score 1):

Olá, veja este exemplo, talvez lhe ajude:

```js
$(document).on("click", "[data-remove-file]", function (e) {

  e.preventDefault();
  
  $(e.target).closest("[data-row]").remove();

});

$(document).on("submit", "form", function (e) {

  //e.preventDefault();
  
  $(e.target).find("[data-mark-remove-file]").each(function (i, chk) {
    
    if ($(chk).is(":checked"))
      $(chk).closest("[data-row]").remove(); 
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
<table>
  <tr data-row>
    <td><input type="file"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" data-mark-remove-file>remove before submit</td>
    <td><a href="#" data-remove-file>remove now</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr data-row>
    <td><input type="file"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" data-mark-remove-file>remove before submit</td>
    <td><a href="#" data-remove-file>remove now</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr data-row>
    <td><input type="file"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" data-mark-remove-file>remove before submit</td>
    <td><a href="#" data-remove-file>remove now</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<button>submit</button>

</form>
```

Comment: interessante sua forma de responder a questão, mas ele quer utilizar um input do multiple, e remover apenas um arquivo desse input, e não vários inputs single... Estou com o mesmo problema que ele.